# Error in NV's implement for glClearNamedFramebufferfi

Tags: opengl, driver, nvidia, graphic, opengl-4

I run across a bug when using OpenGL 4.5 DSA functions, on nvidia's GTX760M
These are three pieces of code:
1. the old fashion

```
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

2. the modern fashion

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_BUFFER, 0);
glClearBufferfi(GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, 0, 1.f, 0);
```

3.the dsa fashion

```
glClearNamedFramebufferfi(0, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, 1.f, 0);
```

But only the first and the second code work. So is this a bug or my mistake?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: When depth test is enabled, i can not draw a simple triangle on default framebuffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a bug of glew, just change the prototype of glClearNamedFramebufferfi to

`typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLCLEARNAMEDFRAMEBUFFERFIPROC) (GLuint framebuffer, GLenum buffer, GLuint drawbuffer, GLfloat depth, GLint stencil);`